# Limit of exponential function with negative base

Tags: limits, exponential-function

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right)^{x+1}$

Above limit having exponent tending to 2(which is even) and base tending to -1/2(negative).
At first glance, it looks like limit is $\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^2$ which is $\frac{1}{4}$, but does this limit even exist?

Comment: While not a formal proof, sometimes it can be helpful to make a graph (desmos) to see what's going on. It's pretty obvious here

Comment: Altho negative bases are defined for exponents to constant integer powers, and to a lesser extent to some ration powers (although *not* all texts allow that), the exponential *function* of $B^x$ *requires* and is defined *only* for $B > 0$ (unless we are dealing with complex numbers).  so $(\frac {x-2}2)^{x+1}$ is not defined for $x < 2$ so you are correct, the limit is meaningless.

Comment: Oh, for *eff* sake to the downvoters!  It was a legitimate question and the OP asked it well and thought about it!  +1 to offset the idiotic downvoters.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent is real, so $ f(x) $ will be defined only for the real $ x $ such that
$$\frac{x-2}{2}>0 \; or\; x>2$$

The function is not well defined near $ x=1$, so we cannot speak about $$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$$